# problems getting while running the docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

I have written DockerFile (See screenshot for reference[image]) or the below snippet.

```
FROM centos:7
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
COPY . . 
ENTRYPOINT ["server.sh", "start"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I am able to build this image (using docker build -t image_name.)
but while running the docker image (docker run -d image_name) I encountered the below error

**docker:Error response from daemon:failed to create shim:OCI runtime create failed:runc create failed: unable to start container  PATH: unknown**

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep

Comment: Although, its not related to the question but using `grep` to extract something from describe output or `yaml` output is a terrible idea. because it may return extra lines which do have `image` string in it.  update your approach to do something like `kubectl get <DEPLOYMENT_NAME>  -o jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[*].image}'`

Answer (score 1):

#### -i (ignore case)

The output of the describe command is similar to this one:

```
Name:                   multitool
Namespace:              codewizard
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 28 Jun 2022 02:28:35 +0300
Labels:                 app=multitool
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=multitool
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=multitool
  Containers:
   network-multitool:
    Image:        praqma/network-multitool
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   multitool-546689b6bb (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

---

The relevant section in the output is this:

```yaml
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=multitool
  Containers:
   network-multitool:
    Image:        praqma/network-multitool
```

- The `Image` entry in this sample is `Image: praqma/network-multitool` with a capital `I`,  so in order to get it you want to ignore the case or otherwise use the `grep Image`

Comment: Of course, if the container's other metadata contains `image` anywhere, it will extract that, too. Better to run a command which _only_ returns the information you seek; or, if that's not possible, properly parse the output (a huge ordeal for many legacy formats).

Comment: Thanks CodeWizard this works for me